# Change CSS in angular on mouseenter

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a dart which is created in one controller and an even schedule which is created in another controller.  Both the dart and the event have unique ids.  I want to be able to hover over the dart and have the event with the same id highlighted and also hover over over the event and have the dart with the same id highlighted. The events are shown on the image on the right side and say shiftstart, BRK ect... I have the the following code which broadcasts the id from the dart controller to the  event schedule controller:

Dart controller:

```
 $scope.clicker = function(id)
  {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("id changed", id);
  }
```

event contoller

```
$scope.$on("id changed", function(event, id)
    {
            for(let i = 0; i < $ctrl.adherence.events.length; i++){
                if($ctrl.adherence.events[i].id == id)
      console.log("id in on: " + $ctrl.adherence.events[i].id + " other id 
      is " + id);
        }
    });
```

Here is my ng-mouseenter in my html for the dart:

(`<img src="${getDartImage(event)}" ng-mouseenter="clicker(${event.id})" class="dart">`);

And my ng-mouseenter for my event schedule

```
<scheduled-event

                            event="event"
                            ng-repeat="event in $ctrl.adherence.events"
                            ng-mouseenter="$ctrl.clicker1($ctrl.adherence.events[$index].id)">



                        </scheduled-event>
```

I am able to match the ids and do a console log but how do change the css of the dart by clicking on on the event and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement ngMouseenter and ngMouseleave on both sides: dart board and score board. Just broadcast an event with a data like ID.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

```
$scope.onDartEnter = function(dartId){
  $rootScope.$broadcast('dartEnter',{id: dartId});
};

$scope.onScoreEnter = function(scoreId){
  $rootScope.$broadcast('scoreEnter',{id: scoreId});
};
```

Change CSS:

```
$scope.$on("scoreEnter", function(event, params){
    var scoreObject = findScoreById(params.id);  // needs implementation
    scoreObject.customClass = 'enter';
});
```

HTML example:

```
<div ng-repeat="score in scores">
  <div id="name" ng-class="score.customClass">{{score.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did add this and I added to my question above but when I mouseenter the dart how do I get the even score with the matching id to highlight and vice versa?